# A line integral as the average of squares of distances

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, multivariable-calculus

Let $A$ be a domain  in $\mathbb R^2$ whose boundary $\gamma $ is a smooth positively oriented curve and whose area is $|A|$.

Find a function $F:\mathbb R^2\to \mathbb R$ such that $$\frac{1}{|A|}\int_\gamma  Fdx+Fdy$$ is the average value of the square of the distance from the origin to a point of $A$.

I guess I should use Green's theorem at some point, but I don't know how exactly, and how to start.
The distance from $(x,y)\in A$ to the origin is $\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$. So the average I believe is $\frac{\sum_{(x,y)\in A} x^2+y^2}{|A|}$? I don't know where to get from this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For notational convenience, let me rename your domain $\Omega$, so that $\gamma = \partial \Omega$ is the positively oriented boundary of $\Omega$.

The average value of an integrable function $f : \Omega \to \mathbb{R}$ on a domain $\Omega$ is
$$
 \frac{1}{\lvert \Omega \rvert} \iint_\Omega f(x,y) \, \mathrm{d}A.
$$
As a result, the average value over a domain $\Omega$ of the square of the distance from the origin is indeed
$$
 \frac{1}{\lvert \Omega \rvert}\iint_\Omega (x^2+y^2) \, \mathrm{d}A.
$$
Now, if $F : \Omega \to \mathbb{R}$ is a $C^1$ function, then by Green's theorem,
$$
 \int_\gamma F \, \mathrm{d}x + F \, \mathrm{d}y = \iint_\Omega (F_x - F_y)\,\mathrm{d}A,
$$
so your task is to reverse engineer a function $F$, such that
$$
\frac{1}{\lvert \Omega \rvert}\int_\gamma F \, \mathrm{d}x + F \, \mathrm{d}y = \frac{1}{\lvert \Omega \rvert}\iint_\Omega (F_x- F_y)\,\mathrm{d}A = \frac{1}{\lvert \Omega \rvert}\iint_\Omega (x^2+y^2) \, \mathrm{d}A;
$$
to do so, it suffices to reverse engineer a function $F$, such that
$$
 \forall (x,y) \in \Omega, \quad F_x(x,y) - F_y(x,y) = x^2 + y^2.
$$
If you can't get started with that, here's an emergency hint:

> Can you find a function $F$, such that $F_x(x,y) = x^2$ and $F_y(x,y) = -y^2$?

Comment: Do you have a typo in the first display?

Comment: Argh, yes, thank you!

Comment: Thanks. It turns out I misinterpreted (or didn't know) the definition of the average value of an integrable function.

Comment: Also, shouldn't there be $F_x-F_y$ instead of $F_y-F_x$?

Comment: You’re quite right.